# Conditionally format inconsistent user input strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a freeform string field that a user inputs a set of values into. This enables the user to enter information in any manner, but also comes with inconsistencies in formatting. For data cleanup purposes, I would like to format the strings to be standard regardless of how they entered them. For instance, I have the following set of data. Notice how the colon is entered in a variety of formats.

```
Description
---------------------------
ARCHIVE PERSONNEL FOLDERS : INACTIVE
ACTIVE PERSONNEL FOLDERS: ACTIVE
ACTIVE AUDIT FOLDERS :ACTIVE
UNKNOWN AUDIT FOLDERS:ACTIVE
ABC CLIENT FOLDERS  : INACTIVE
DEF CLIENT FOLDERS :  ACTIVE
```

I would like to format the string so that the colon is immeditately appended to the word it comes before, and has a single space following.

```
Description
---------------------------
ARCHIVE PERSONNEL FOLDERS: INACTIVE
ACTIVE PERSONNEL FOLDERS: ACTIVE
ACTIVE AUDIT FOLDERS: ACTIVE
UNKNOWN AUDIT FOLDERS: ACTIVE
ABC CLIENT FOLDERS: INACTIVE
DEF CLIENT FOLDERS: ACTIVE
```

What is the best approach to format the data as desired and to account for any manner of incorrect colon formatting (space before, no space, space before and after, two spaces before, etc.)?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code and tell us how the behavior it exhibits is different than the behavior you were expecting. As a hint, [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) will be your friend here...

Comment: Beyond that, this string should probably be broken up. There are two types of data here, the `NVARCHAR` name (`ARCHIVE PERSONNEL FOLDERS`) and the `BIT` IsActive. I would put the name in one column and the IsActive in a separate column. This allows you to query the db using the IsActive column instead of having to parse the string to do so.

Comment: @LewsTherin This is a 3rd party database - altering the schema isn't an option. I'm cleansing the data for reporting purposes.

Comment: Fair enough, but what about my first comment? SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 3):

This should work regardless of the number of spaces before and after the colon

```
declare @table table([Description] varchar(256))
insert into @table
values
('ARCHIVE PERSONNEL FOLDERS : INACTIVE'),
('ACTIVE PERSONNEL FOLDERS: ACTIVE'),
('ACTIVE AUDIT FOLDERS :ACTIVE'),
('UNKNOWN AUDIT FOLDERS:ACTIVE'),
('ABC CLIENT FOLDERS  : INACTIVE'),
('DEF CLIENT FOLDERS :  ACTIVE')

select
    [Description]
    ,rtrim(substring([Description],0,CHARINDEX(':',[Description]))) + ': ' + ltrim(substring([Description],CHARINDEX(':',[Description])+1,len([Description])))
from
    @table
```

Comment: Doesn't completely work; For the 4th row you will have a space before colon. The reason is that there are 2 spaces before it.

Comment: Please **PLEASE** stop writing code for those who don't show effort to solve their own problem first. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service and you should value your time more than writing code for someone who can't be bothered to attempt to solve their problem before asking someone to do it for them.

Comment: Relax @LewsTherin it's Friday and I'm procrastinating taking a final. Besides [everyone does it from time to time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092898/6167855) wouldn't you agree? Cheers.

Comment: @LewsTherin  Pretty sure scismon is over 18 years old, so this falls into the "His time, his choice" bucket.

Comment: This worked well, thanks @scsimon. And for what it's worth, I realize this was a pretty simple request, but instead of parsing my unsuccessful attempts of utilizing `SUBSTRING`, I thought someone might be able to more efficiently chime in. @scsimon did that and I'm grateful.

Comment: cheers @PicoDeGallo, all DBA's hate free form fields on the front end :)

Comment: @scsimon Not me.  I dig analyzing unstructured data.  It is a great feeling to accomplish something that everyone else said "it can't be done".

Comment: Hahaha @JohnCappelletti you enjoy the headaches more than I!

Answer (score 1):

**Assumptions:**

I made a couple assumptions when coming up with this answer. There are workarounds to these assumptions if they are not valid, but figured it was best to start with the easiest scenario.

1) There will never be a `.` entered in the freeform string field.

2) There will never be more than one `:` included in the freeform string field.

**Sample Data Setup:**

```
declare @table table
    (
        description varchar(100) not null
    )

insert into @table
    values  ('ARCHIVE PERSONNEL FOLDERS : INACTIVE')
            , ('ACTIVE PERSONNEL FOLDERS: ACTIVE')
            , ('ACTIVE AUDIT FOLDERS :ACTIVE')
            , ('UNKNOWN AUDIT FOLDERS:ACTIVE')
            , ('ABC CLIENT FOLDERS  : INACTIVE')
            , ('DEF CLIENT FOLDERS :  ACTIVE')
```

**Answer:**

Just like Lewis Therin said in the comments to the question, `REPLACE` is quite useful here. It will help set things up for a outside the documented purpose, but reliable, use of the function called [parsename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql).

The select statement below splits each of the strings into two, based on where the `:` is, trims off any extra spaces from each of them, and then concatenates them back together with the specified `:` (colon with space) between them.

```
select rtrim(ltrim(parsename(replace(t.description, ':', '.'), 2))) + ': ' + rtrim(ltrim(parsename(replace(t.description, ':', '.'), 1))) as description
from @table as t
```

**Results:**

```
Description
-------------------------------------
ARCHIVE PERSONNEL FOLDERS: INACTIVE
ACTIVE PERSONNEL FOLDERS: ACTIVE
ACTIVE AUDIT FOLDERS: ACTIVE
UNKNOWN AUDIT FOLDERS: ACTIVE
ABC CLIENT FOLDERS: INACTIVE
DEF CLIENT FOLDERS: ACTIVE
```